# Java Process sh command with root credentials

Tags: java, process, sh, sudo

I'm trying to build a java method to execute an 'sh' command on terminal using Process class. It looks like this:

```
Process p;
String[] cmd = { "sh", "/dir/file.sh"};
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

After setting up some permissions I can fire the command manually through console without sudo credentials and it will do the job, but java runs from tomcat at the server and the tomcat user doesn't appear to get through permits, even though the target sh file has been given -rwxr-xr-x flags.

I was wondering how could I set the same cmd String[] for it to execute like root user, something like:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S sh /dir/file.sh
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
String[] cmd = { "echo 'password' |", "sudo -S", "sh", "/dir/file.sh"};
```

Comment: use jsch library for such operations.. for your reference http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html

Comment: Did you tried ProcessBuilder ??

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not closing this thread yet. I got around it in a "peculiar" way. I checked both librarues and I'm really interested in both, I will try them to fix the issue properly shortly and I'll let yu know.